# Tell if parity check matrix is linearly independent

Tags: group-theory, coding-theory

I know these are parity check matrixes of linear codes $C_1$ and $C_2$.

$H_1=
\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{matrix}$

$H_2=
\begin{matrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{matrix}$

I need to find the number of code words belonging to each of the codes $C_1, C_2$. I know that I can solve $Hx=0$ and get all words that way. But I have seen examples were this is done by computing the dimension as $k = cols - rows$ and thereby the words are $2^k$ and saying that this can be done because these parity check *matrixes rows are obviously linearly independent*.

How can I easily verify that this is the case? I suspect there is a neat trick involved, and not much actual computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many times the $(n-k)\times n$ parity check matrix $H$ of a $[n,k]$ code
is written in the form 
$$H = [P_{(n-k)\times(k)} \mid I_{(n-k)\times (n-k)} ]$$
which makes the independence of the rows obvious.  But for your matrices,
you can try finding the *reduced-echelon* matrix with the same row space.
For example, what happens if you add the first and second rows of $H_1$ into
the third row?